# libgdx actor touchHandling

Tags: java, android, touch, libgdx

I am currently experience some funny issue with touchHandling on LibGdx . My code is as follows:-

```
testCount=0;
ThisButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    testCount++;
    gameLog("touchDown - testCount: " + testCount);
    return true;
}
public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    testCount++;
    gameLog("touchUp - testCount: " + testCount);
}
```

});

Theoretically, testCount should only return 2 (1 for touchDown, and 1 for touchUp) when the actor are touched. However, my LogCat output returns multiple calls on single tapped.

```
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchDown - testCount: 1
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchDown - testCount: 2
.
.
.
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchDown - testCount: 177
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchDown - testCount: 178
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchUp - testCount: 179
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchUp - testCount: 180
.
.
.
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchUp - testCount: 355
GreatGame: GameScreen: touchUp - testCount: 356
```

I am not sure where I went wrong.

Thank you very much and your help is much appreciated.

Regards
Zi

Comment: have to tried it in some other device?

Comment: Thanks buddy, i had tried on both my samsung android and desktop. same result on both desktop and android phone. not sure where when wrong

Comment: It is indeed not the behaviour I'd have expected. Maybe try using a ClickListener http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html

Comment: I just tested it and that code works flawlessly, using      Gdx.app.log("TAG", "touchDown - testCount: " + testCount); instead of your gameLog method of course, your problem is in other part of your code or probably a bug on your device screen.

Comment: I'm suspecting the gameLog method :p

Comment: what is the gameLog method?

Comment: What is the gameLog method @Lestat ?

Comment: Your method "gameLog("touchDown - testCount: " + testCount);" what happens there?

Comment: `public void gameLog (String message){
  if (isgameLogEnable) {
   Gdx.app.log("thisGame", getName() + ": " + message);
  }
 }`