# libgdx actor touchHandling issue

Tags: java, android, touch, libgdx

I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798403/libgdx-actor-touchhandling) before but it seems that I am heading nowhere even though I did receive help from many people. Therefore I have done a small experiment. I have created a test project just to test out the LibGdx touch handling. This touchTester project somehow replicates my problem. Attached (attachment removed) please find the entire project source code (zipped file). The upCounter in following code should only return 1 since it should only be needed to run once.

```
// upCounter is = 0;        
this.libgdxImg.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return true;
}

public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    upCounter++;
    touchtester.doLog("upCounter = " + upCounter);
    }
});
```

However, when I run it, it give me this result

```
catland: touchTester: render
catland: touchTester: render
catland: touchTester: upCounter = 1
catland: touchTester: upCounter = 2
...
catland: touchTester: upCounter = 94
catland: touchTester: upCounter = 95
catland: touchTester: render
catland: touchTester: render
```

May I ask someone's help to test it out? I have absolutely no idea where the problem came from. I setup my project using the gdx-setup-ui.jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the most important part here. The given code where you add your `new InputListener...` is inside your `render()` method.

That's not how it should be. What it basically does is adding a new, anonymous `InputListener` to your image in every single frame. All those listeners will get notified and they all add 1 to your `upcounter`. Move the code to your `show()` method and it should work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks @noone. that make sense. but, if i place those code in the show() method, how do i disable/re-enable the button/InputListener during the application session?

Comment: `this.libgdxImg.cleaerListeners()`, or by disabling the whole stage `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null)`

Comment: Thanks @noone, what about re-enable it?