# about LibGdx addListener

Tags: java, android, touch, libgdx, listener

I believe this question has been asked before, but it seems that I am a bit unlucky to find it. My question is how do I enabling a button/actor’s `addListener` in middle of the process? Take for example, on assets loading screen in between activity screen (let assume that user finished Stage A, the loading screen is to load assets for Stage B), the continue button can only be enabled (displayed previously, but not enable) after the all assets is loaded. If I add the addListener in to the `render()` section, it will create lots of anonymous inputListener as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161809/libgdx-actor-touchhandling-issue/22164061#22164061). However, I don’t think it will work if I place it in `show()` section. My question is where should I place this `addListener` in order to make an actor touchable yet does not create those anonymous `inputListener`? And what is the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to create a `ClickListener` instead of an `InputListener` and add it as usual. Inside of the Listener you check if the loading is done. If it's done you do what ever you want to do. If not you return without any action.

To give you an example how to add an `ClickListener` to a TextButton which should already do your task:

```
    TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.font = new BitmapFont();
    style.font.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    continue= new TextButton("continue",
            style);

    continue.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
             if(manager.update()){ //returns true if the AssetManager is done in case you use an AssetManager
                  basegameclass.setScreen("menu"); //sets the menu screen
             }else{
             //not done do nothing or do something else like showing loading not done
             }
        }
    });
```

To add it to different actors or Buttons it should be simmelar. Just take care that the Stage where the Button is added also is the `Inputprocessor`. So make sure you added it like this `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`

In this case i don't think, that you need a whole `InputListener` simply take the ClickListener for this small task. The `InputListener` gives you a wider range of methods which you dont need i think. It is used to detect `touchups` and `touchdowns` and slide events and much more which you dont need for a button i think. Maybe for actors that you drag around.

*you create this all inside of the constructor of the screen. Never do such things inside of the render method since it would create a new listener every frame. (60 per second!)*

Comment: Thanks @Bennx. In theory, I should have something (e.g. boolean) to disable/enable each button if I want to control it.

For inputListener vs ClickListener, in term of memory usage and physical processor usage, which method will consume less?

Comment: I dont really think that this matters. But in your case you dont need to take care if it is an up or downevent and so on. You simply need to know if its clicked so i'd take the `ClickListener`. It is more simple i think. But if you like to you can take  an regular `InputListener`. Just to mention. The **ClickListeneter extends the InputListener**! So In the end its the same just a bit more simple to use for simple cases.