# libgdx play sound or music - best practice

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

Like inputListener should be place/code in the show() section, not in render() section since it will create lots of hidden listener. My question is:-

What is the correct way to setup/play sound/music? LibGdx will play the same sound multiple times (with very very short interval) if i place the sound.play() in the render section. what is the best method implement this?

**Comment Added**: The answer provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296997/about-libgdx-addlistener), ***especially the italic section***, highlight that this thing should not be place in the render() section. my question is that where should place the code without play the same sound in every frame?

**Comment Added**: theoretically, the sound in the following code should only played once, right? however, if you listen carefully, it is playing multiple times with a very short interval. that is my problem. hopefully this time I explain my problem well...

```
private int processStatus = 0;

private void show() {
    thisSound = programApp.assetManager.get("sound/thisSound.mp3", Sound.class);

    thisButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            doLog("thisButton down");
            return true;
        }
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            doLog("thisButton up");
            processStatus = 1;
        }
    });
}

private void render() {
    if (processStatus == 0){
        //do something
    } else if (processStatus == 1){
        thisSound.play();
        //do something else
        processStatus = 2;
    } else if (processStatus == 2){
        //do whatever 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own AudioManager. It's always nice to have managers for these things. The code gets separated and it's structurally clean.

I don't understand the problem really? If you pick up a coin you should play a sound, right? Well this coin should probably be removed when we collide with it? Then if the coin no longer exists there will be no sound to play on the next frame since we cant collide with something that's been removed?

Example:

```
    for(Coin coin : coins){
    if(player.collidesWith(coin)){
        playSound();
        coins.remove(coin, true);
    }
}
```

You always keep your objects in a collection so you only render/update those in the collection. When the above collision occurs, the object will no longer exist in the collection thus making it **impossible** for a sound to be played.

Comment: thanks for you help, mate. i have added additional comment in the question section. hope that help explaining my problem.

Answer (score 1):

the answer to this question is very tricky, as there is no such thing as best practice.
Implementation varies according to situation.

Here is what i prefer to do.

For music
 in the constructor of the screen where music is to be played

1. Close all the music if any is playing if u need to play a different music from previous screen
2. music.setLoopable(true);

3,        Music. play();

for sounds.

as far as sounds are concerned as sounds are to be played only once when a specific event occurs.
for instance a coin is taken, a powerup is taken, a collision.
so sound must be triggerd in the specific condition so that i plays only once.

Comment: Thanks @kumar-saurabh. Your answer is quite useful, however, it is not something that i am looking for. The answer provided in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296997/about-libgdx-addlistener), _especially the italic section_, highlight that this thing should not be place in the render() section. my question is that where should place the code without play the same sound in every frame?